# iTextSharp watermark multiline text

Tags: itext

I have seen answers to question of how to add text watermark to an existing PDF document using iTextSharp. My question is how can we do multiline text. Is there a way to do this without having multiple PdfContentByte defined. I have tried to insert a newline character with no luck.

Here is the code from the internet. I just added

```
pdfData.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, editDate, (pageRectangle.Width / 2) + 100, (pageRectangle.Height / 2) - 100, 45);
```

as the second line to get the second line of the watermark, it works but uses same parameters (color, size, etc.) as the first.

```
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageRectangle = PDFreader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
//pdfcontentbyte object contains graphics and text content of page returned by pdfstamper    
PdfContentByte pdfData = stamper.GetOverContent(1);

//create fontsize for watermark    
pdfData.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 120);

//create new graphics state and assign opacity    
PdfGState graphicsState = new PdfGState();
graphicsState.FillOpacity = 0.2F;
//set graphics state to pdfcontentbyte    
pdfData.SetGState(graphicsState);

//set color of watermark    
pdfData.SetColorFill(iTextSharp.text.Color.BLUE);

//indicates start of writing of text    
pdfData.BeginText();

//show text as per position and rotation    
pdfData.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, "E D I T E D" , (pageRectangle.Width / 2), (pageRectangle.Height / 2), 45);
pdfData.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, editDate, (pageRectangle.Width / 2) + 100, (pageRectangle.Height / 2) - 100, 45);
//call endText to invalid font set    

pdfData.EndText();
```

Comment: Please show your code. There is no reason why multiline watermarks should not be possible.

Comment: so is it working or not now? what is the value of `editedDate`?

Comment: as I said it works but uses same parameters (color, size, etc.) as the first but I want the second one different size. editDate gets the value with no problem

Comment: Have you tried making a 2-pass process, first the text, then the date? Or retrieve two different `PdfContentByte` instances, and set the desired color, size, etc... to each?

Comment: as I asked in my question "Is there a way to do this without having multiple PdfContentByte defined."

Comment: Have a 2-pass approach. What is the issue with having 2 `PdfContentByte` instances? Memory usage?